# Janrain (RPX) with file: protocol

Tags: file, cordova, protocols, janrain, file-uri

Janrain is not working for me, if the current webpage is opened from localhost with `file:` protocol. I got the following error in the popup frame:

`No webpage was found for the web address: file://X.rpxnow.com/openid/embed?token_url=Y`

How can I avoid this? I would like to create a mobile application with PhoneGap, and it looks like it use `file:` protocol.

Thanks in advance,
Andras

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `https` scheme (or perhaps the `http` scheme).  The `file` scheme will not work.  The `file` scheme pulls files from the client's filesystem.  You need to make the API call against the remote rpxnow.com server, so `file` will not work.

You will probably need to override the scheme in your code.  If you're not sure how to do that, post your code and I or someone else will no doubt try to explain how to do it.